# Getting a list of unique embedded/nested objects in a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following MongoDB "recipes" collection:

```
{
  "title" : "Macaroni and Cheese",
  "ingredients" : [
    { "name" : "noodles", "qty" : "2 c" },
    { "name" : "butter", "qty" : "2 tbl" },
    { "name" : "cheese", "qty" : "1 c" },
  ]
},
{
  "title" : "Pound Cake",
  "ingredients" : [
    { "name" : "sugar", "qty" : "1 lb" },
    { "name" : "butter", "qty" : "1 lb" },
    { "name" : "flour", "qty" : "1 lb" },
  ]
},
{
  "title" : "Dough",
  "ingredients" : [
    { "name" : "water", "qty" : "2 c" },
    { "name" : "butter", "qty" : "8 tbl" },
    { "name" : "flour", "qty" : "1 lb" },
  ]
}
```

I wish to write a query to generate a "shopping list" of items to buy to make all the recipes. So I basically want to return the ingredients "noodles", "butter", "cheese", "sugar", "butter", "flour", "water". I don't want duplicates. (Sugar and butter, for example appear in more than one recipe, but I only want to return them once, i.e. no duplicates.)

Is it possible to create such a query in MongoDB and if so, what would this query be? Or would it necessitate me to create a separate collection for "ingredients"?

Comment: do you care about quantities?  doesn't make much sense not to get those - how much sugar will you need to buy?

Comment: Well, this was just a simplified example of my actual problem. In my actual problem each instance of "ingredient" will actually have the exact same field values i.e. "flour" will always have a "qty" of "1 lb" and "butter" will always have a "qty" of "8tbl" in all "recipes". I'm not concerned about an aggregate value (summation) of quantities as you suggest. I would, however, like to also have the "qty" field returned along with the name such that I have a full representation of the "ingredient", eg. { "name" : "flour", "qty" : "1 lb" }.

Comment: db.recipes.distinct('ingredients.name') is the best solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following query would give you the bare list minus any duplicates:

```
db.recipes.aggregate([{$unwind:"$ingredients"},{$group:{_id:"$ingredients.name"}}])
```

More work would be necessary to add the quantities.  It would be easier if the unit for the quantities was specified separately.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it gives me what I require, but the use of the aggregate also makes it possible to include some more fields from "ingredient" (using the "$first" operator) than just the name. (It could even aggregate the "qty" fields if I so wished.) So this answer is a bit more powerful and is the answer that helped me solve the problem. c.P.u1's answer is the simpler one if I only wanted the "name" returned (as stated in my question) and so I am upvoting that answer too.

Comment: @All - How can we do it using Spring Data Mongo API ?

Answer (score 38):

Use `distinct` to find an array of distinct values for `ingredients.name`

```
db.recipes.distinct('ingredients.name')
```

yields `[ "butter", "cheese", "noodles", "flour", "sugar", "water" ]`

Comment: This is the best solution -)

Comment: How can we sort the result set in same query ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the full aggregate pipeline you were looking for:

```
db.recipes.aggregate([
       {$unwind:"$ingredients"},
       {$group:{_id:"$ingredients.name",
                quantity:{$first:"$ingredients.qty"},
                recipes:{$push:"$title"},
                total:{$sum:1}
               }
       },
       {$project:{_id:0,ingredient:"$_id", total:1, quantity:1, recipes:1}
])
```

This unwinds the arrays, groups by ingredient, adds them up to see how many recipes need them, keeps the quantity fields which is going to be the same in your use case, and adds a list of recipes it's used in.  Last step renames the grouped on field to "ingredient".

Result:

```
{ "quantity" : "1 lb", "recipes" : [  "Pound Cake",  "Dough" ], "total" : 2, "ingredient" : "flour" }
{ "quantity" : "2 c", "recipes" : [  "Dough" ], "total" : 1, "ingredient" : "water" }
{ "quantity" : "1 lb", "recipes" : [  "Pound Cake" ], "total" : 1, "ingredient" : "sugar" }
{ "quantity" : "1 c", "recipies" : [  "Macaroni and Cheese" ], "total" : 1, "ingredient" : "cheese" }
{ "quantity" : "2 tbl", "recipes" : [  "Macaroni and Cheese",  "Pound Cake",  "Dough" ], "total" : 3, "ingredient" : "butter" }
{ "quantity" : "2 c", "recipes" : [  "Macaroni and Cheese" ], "total" : 1, "ingredient" : "noodles" }
```

Answer (score 2):

A funny way of doing it in the mongoshell using `foreach` operator

```
var list = [];
db.recepies.find(
  {},
  {'ingredients.name' : 1, _id : 0}
).forEach(function(doc){
  var ingredients = doc.ingredients;
  for (var i=0; i< ingredients.length; i++){
    var ingredient = ingredients[i].name;
    if (list.indexOf(ingredient) == -1){
       list.push(ingredient)
    }
  }
});
```

after this `list` will contain all the elements. P.S. I am sure this is also possible with aggregation framework.