# How to find documents with unique records in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a collection with several documents in it of jobs to process using another system. I look up 5 objects from this table like this:

```
Work.find({status: 'new'})
  .sort({priority: 'desc'})
  .limit(5)
  .exec(function (err, work){})
```

There is another field on these documents which determines that only one job with a given unique value can be ran at the same time.

For example these 3 jobs:

```
{uniqueVal: 1, priority: 1, type: "scrape", status:"new"}
{uniqueVal: 1, priority: 1, type: "scrape", status:"new"}
{uniqueVal: 2, priority: 1, type: "scrape", status:"new"}
```

There are 2 records with the uniqueVal of 1. Is there anything I can do to only pull one record with the value 1?

Note: These values are not predetermined values like in the example, they are ObjectIds of other documents.

I've looked into Distinct(), but it seems like it only returns the actual unique values, not the documents themselves.

Comment: Have you checked aggregation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923536/getting-a-list-of-unique-embedded-nested-objects-in-a-mongodb-document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best choice is to use aggregation.

You can $group by uniqueVal
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

And use $first for the other values
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've started working out an aggregation but running into some issues. It seems like aggregations return completely new documents. I want my actual work objects back with every field included. The _id must be the _id of the work object, not my unique value. $group seems to do the opposite.

Comment: But maybe I can use this to get a list of my unique objects with the _id of the work object and then run an $or query to pull back just those documents. I think i can make that work

Comment: during the $group stage you can do {$group: {_id: "$uniqueVal", tmpId: {$first: "$_id"}}}

Comment: Yup that's pretty much what I did, and its working great, thanks!