# MongoDB query for aggregating dynamic documents on unique field

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, nosql

There are a lot of questions on this all over SO, but none of them answers my question, so here goes:

**How can I find documents with unique values and then return the *complete* documents?**

I have looked at e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655040/how-to-find-documents-with-unique-values-in-mongodb) and [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30655134/4066044) to all similar questions seem to say the same thing. Use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first).

The problem I have with this is that I have a database where the documents have some differentiations between the fields, and more fields may come in at a later stage. So how do I return the *complete* document when trying to retrieve the latest document containin a given value?

Example:

```
{uniqueVal: 1, priority: 1, type: "storage", status:"open", validated: "true", sorting: "desc"}
{uniqueVal: 1, priority: 1, type: "plain", status:"new", validated: "false"}
{uniqueVal: 2, priority: 1, type: "banana", status:"new", randomizedfield: "true"}
```

Should become

```
{uniqueVal: 1, priority: 1, type: "storage", status:"open", validated: "true", sorting: "desc"}
{uniqueVal: 2, priority: 1, type: "banana", status:"new", randomizedfield: "true"}
```

**How can I retrieve the documents by unique field "uniqueVal", while not having to *hard-code* which fields have have to be returned?**

(I am querying from Java)

Comment: How do you determine whether the document is latest?

Comment: What do you mean with unique value: the uniqueVal field in your collection OR a document with a unique field value in general?

Comment: @chridam does not matter. The problem I have is how to return the full document

Comment: @matthiasboesinger I want to filter so that I only get one of the documents with uniqueVal: 1, and one with uniqueVal: 2. Should I update the example to make it clearer?

Comment: A bit misleading as you mentioned in your question _So how do I return the complete document when trying to retrieve the latest document containin a given value?_ So, the question still stands, what determines a latest document?

Comment: The aggregation commands allows for a $sort, so if you have anything you wouls like to sort on, then you can add it. My question only contained an example (copied from another SO-question) and as such I don't care which one of the uniqueVal:1 is returned :)
Notably, the default sorting should be _id.

Comment: Found the solution, but thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [aggregation variable $$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)

Running this command (Mongo Shell) returns the filtered result that I wanted. The returned format is a bit different but the importance is that it works as it should.

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id": "$uniqueVal",
            document:{
                $first:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Returning the result

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "document" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b354e6e9d72472495b1de5"),
                "uniqueVal" : 2,
                "priority" : 1,
                "type" : "banana",
                "status" : "new",
                "randomizedfield" : "true"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "document" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b354e6e9d72472495b1de3"),
                "uniqueVal" : 1,
                "priority" : 1,
                "type" : "storage",
                "status" : "open",
                "validated" : "true",
                "sorting" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just from a conceptual point of view, it seems to me that what you're looking for is not practical:

Looking for documents that match unique values suppose a distinct query, which targets the corresponding field (uniqueVal).
This is fine, a database can find unique values for a given field.

The problem comes in when you want to fetch documents that match those 'unique values': this is mixing aggregated values with individual rows.

To illustrate this, look at your own example: your original collection contains 3 entries, but the result you **wish for** only contains 2. On what ground have you discarded the document with **'type'='plain'**?

This is why unique values are accompanied with AGGREGATED fields, because otherwise there is no rule to include or exclude other rows/documents.

Comment: One instance where this can be used could be to keep a history of changes in the database.
Say I am keeping test data for multiple products. Whenever I get a new test result I write the data to the DB, but I don't overwrite the existing test result in order to, at a later time, be able to fetch the history for a given product. But I also want the latest retult for each unique product in order to display the current status of the system.
Hope that explains the principles behind the question